# does this statement refer to futur tense?

Tags: learning

commemoration to be held for victims. I mean: do these have same meaning "commemoration will be held for victims"

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The full formal version would be "A commemoration *is* to be held for [the] victims", and is indeed a way of expressing the future.  In newspaper headlines, this would usually be shortened to "Commemoration to be held for victims."